# Creating txt file with a custom data type

Tags: file, haskell

I have a custom data type:

```
data TextEditor = TextEditor [Char] [Char] [Char] deriving (Show)
```

This is used to hold text before a cursor then after the cursor and then hold only selections that are made.

I wish to have a function 'save' that allows the user to save the contents of this datatype to a txt file. My current versions is:

```
save :: TextEditor -> String -> IO()
save (TextEditor b a x) f = writeFile f (TextEditor b a x)
```

but `writeFile` takes a `String` and I am passing three `[Char]` is there a way to convert this into a string or is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: You will need a serializer that transforms Haskell objects into a stream of bytes (or characters). Perhaps you can use `Data.Aeson` to construct a JSON string.

Comment: side-note: you are not passing in three `[Char]` but a `TextEditor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you `derive (Show, Read)` you can then

```
save :: TextEditor -> FilePath -> IO ()
save editor f = writeFile f $ show editor

restore:: FilePath -> IO (Maybe TextEditor)
restore f = readMay <$> readFile f
```

### Note

- `readMay` is from the package [safe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe).
- `read`/`show`/`String` are very inefficient, so the remark about using something like `aeson` for (de-)serialization is a good idea.
- if you have a custom `show` instance - a derived `read` won't work.

Comment: Is there any reason you used `readMay` instead of `readMaybe` from base?